Power Automate Do until finishes even tho condition is not met
I have a power automate flow that has a Do until action but it goes to the next action even tho condition is not met, I attached an image of the Do Until condition, where do I asign that value and one example of the value when it skips it.



I'm not sure what to change, because I can see the value is false at the last iteration of the Do Until, but suddenly goes to the next action
Edit:
There is a Count and Timeout option, for default is 60 times and one hour, if your Loop takes more than an hour it automatically skips the next iteration. Adding more time fixed the issue!
